# Trouble with running a parallelized script from a driver script

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I'm trying to parallelize my code, and I finally got the parfor loops set up such that Matlab doesn't crash every time. However, I've now got an error that I can't seem to figure out.

I have a driver script (Driver12.m) that calls the script that I'm trying to parallelize (Worker12.m). If I run Worker12.m directly, it usually finishes with no problem. However, every time I try to run it from Driver12.m, it either 1) causes Matlab to crash, or 2) throws a strange error at me. Here's some of my code:

```
%Driver script
run('(path name)/Worker12.m');

%Relevant worker script snippet
parfor q=1:number_of_ranges
    timenumber = squeeze(new_TS(q,:,:));
    timenumber_shift = circshift(timenumber, [0 1]);
    for m = 1:total_working_channels
        timenumberm = timenumber(m,:);
        for n = 1:total_working_channels
            R_P(m,n,q) = mean(timenumberm.*conj(timenumber(n,:)),2);
            R_V(m,n,q) = mean(timenumberm.*conj(timenumber_shift(n,:)),2);
        end
    end
end
```

Outcome #1: "Matlab has encountered an unexpected error and needs to close."

Outcome #2: "An UndefinedFunction error was thrown on the workers for ''. This might be because the file containing '' is not accessible on the workers. Use addAttachedFiles(pool, files) to specify the required files to be attached. See the documentation for 'parallel.Pool/addAttachedFiles' for more details. Caused by: Undefined function or variable ""."

However, if I run Worker12.m directly, it works fine. It's only when I run it from the driver script that I get issues. Obviously, this error message from Outcome #2 isn't all that useful. Any suggestions?

Edit: So I created a toy example that reproduces an error, but now both my toy example and the original code are giving me a new, 3rd error. Here's the toy example:

```
%Driver script
run('parpoolexample.m')

%parpoolexample.m
clear all
new_TS = rand([1000,32,400]);
[number_of_ranges,total_working_channels,~] = size(new_TS);
R_P = zeros(total_working_channels,total_working_channels,number_of_ranges);
R_V = zeros(total_working_channels,total_working_channels,number_of_ranges);

parfor q=1:number_of_ranges
    timenumber = squeeze(new_TS(q,:,:));
    timenumber_shift = circshift(timenumber, [0 1]);
    for m = 1:total_working_channels
        timenumberm = timenumber(m,:);
        for n = 1:total_working_channels
            R_P(m,n,q) = mean(timenumberm.*conj(timenumber(n,:)),2);
            R_V(m,n,q) = mean(timenumberm.*conj(timenumber_shift(n,:)),2);
        end
    end
end
```

Outcome #3: "Index exceeds matrix dimensions (line 7)."

So, at the 'parfor' line, it's saying that I'm exceeding the matrix dimensions, even though I believe that should not be the case. Now I can't even get my original script to recreate Outcomes #1 or #2.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error by minimising your code to a very simple example which you could post in its entirety?

Comment: The Worker script is ~1500 lines long, but I'll see if I can create a mini-example that reproduces the error. It might take a bit.

Comment: @lhcgeneva I added an example. Now, I can't get my code to recreate the previous outcomes (which is good in the sense that this error message looks more helpful than the others, but frustrating in the sense that I didn't change anything major so I have no idea why it's behaving differently).

Comment: On my machine your new example is working just fine, are you sure there's no typo anywhere?

Comment: I copied and pasted my code directly from Matlab into my edit here, so there shouldn't be a typo. It works fine for me if I run parpoolexample.m directly, but as soon as I go into the command line and say "run('parpoolexample.m')", I get an error.

Comment: Have you cleared your workspace and/or restarted Matlab, just to make sure nothing is fishy there? For me it runs, both from the command line as well as from the script

Comment: I cleared the workspace and tried again. If I go to the command line and type "parpoolexample", it runs fine. If I try "run('parpoolexample.m')", I get the matrix dimensions error. Very odd.

Comment: If I copy the command from your above comment, it runs perfectly fine for me, so I have no idea what could be going on there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `run` with parallel language constructs like `parfor` and `spmd`. Unfortunately it doesn't work very well. Instead, use `cd` or `addpath` to let MATLAB see your script.

Comment: I ran the code overnight last night without using `run` (instead I just changed directories), and it worked perfectly fine. It looks like the `run` command was in fact the issue.